# Org mode time sheet

Tags: emacs, report, customization, org-mode, clock

I'd like to get a custom "timesheet" report.

Curently, I do have the following:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("r" "Weekly Timesheet"
               ((agenda ""))
               ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Weekly timesheet")
                (org-agenda-span 'week)
                (org-agenda-start-on-weekday 1)
                (org-agenda-start-with-clockreport-mode t)
                (org-agenda-time-grid nil))) t)
```

It works as expected, except that I'm not interested in seeing the agenda views for the 7 days: I just want the clockreport, nothing more.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I've never used the clock feature, so I don't have a specific answer for you.  That being said, I am familiar with the org-agenda-skip... functions:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-agenda-views.html  Perhaps that will assist you to eliminate unwanted entries.

Comment: You put me on a good track, for sure. However, I don't know how to remove the "S-expr" events (such as birthdays or computed events). And, I can't get rid of the agenda title for every day, even with `(org-agenda-format-date "")`: there it leaves an empty line for every day. The `\n` seems to be hardcoded somewhere...

Comment: I believe what you are seeking is a highly customized agenda view, which is possible, but will require an investment of a substantial amount of time modifying the source code of `org-agenda-list` and the functions it uses -- e.g., `org-agenda-get-...`.  Rather than using something like the `org-agenda-list` family of functions, perhaps consider using either a tag / property search (i.e., `org-tags-view`) or a word search (i.e., `org-search-view`) using the built-in agenda commands:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  Both of those searches do not insert dividers.

Comment: If you would like to modify the source code for `org-agenda-list`, have a look at the section of code: `(if (stringp org-agenda-format-date) (format-time-string org-agenda-format-date (org-time-from-absolute date)) (funcall org-agenda-format-date date)) "\n")`.  You may not need the text-properties that follow if you eliminate the date . . .  I would suggest creating an entirely new function with a different name and leave `org-agenda-list` as-is.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `clocktable` block. I use this to see a weekly recap of where I spent my time.  You can setup a simple one like the following:

```
    #+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda-with-archives :block lastweek
    #+END:
```

Put your cursor on the BEGIN or END and hit the trusty `C-cC-c` to evaluate the clock table in-place.  It will list the file, headline and time spent on the tasks.

In my example above, the *scope* defines where to look for the clocked items.  In this case, I chose the agenda files and associated archives.  For the *block* of time, I used `lastweek` to get the last 7 days.

There are many more options for configuring just what you need.  Read more at
http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html

Comment: Thanks. I knew about that, but that's for within a file. I'd like to see the current count in a temporary buffer, in a way, by making it a custom agenda view. Something I can call on demand, not something hard-wired in some file.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this helps, but you may want to check out Tom Marble's timesheet.el. You should be able to install it from MELPA. Although it does not integrate with org agenda, this seems like the most thorough way to generate timesheet reports.

http://emacslife.com/emacs-chats/chat-tom-marble.html

https://github.com/tmarble/timesheet.el

The sample org file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmarble/timesheet.el/master/share/yoyodyne.org